# Android Studio: EditText is not updating

Tags: android-studio

I created a EditText and a Text Widget. The app should divide the written Number by 2 and show the result. But it also should be updated all the time. So if i write 4 then it should say 2 and if I write 10 it should say 5. Without a Button to confirm.
Have you an idea how to do so?

Sincerely, tobi

Answer (score 0):

you could use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and use `onTextChange`

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      String value= EditText.getText().toString();
      int finalValue=Integer.parseInt(value)/2;    
      TextView.setText(String.valueOf(finalValue));
   }
  });

 }
```